# Python - Unable to Replace Long String Values in DataFrame using pd.replace or re.sub

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe which consists of a column with weird formatted string output. The data file is about 50k lines but the strings are repeating, there are about 10 unique strings in it. I am trying to do is to have them replaced with something more meaningful.

below is the snapshot of the raw data how it looks:

`data = pd.DataFrame({"x (days in month [date]) (2 month avg)", "avg_12_mon", "database_secondary_ (month from last event) (3 month avg)"}, columns = ["Name"])`

```
index              Name
  0        x (days in month [date]) (2 month avg)
  1        avg_12_mon
  2        database_secondary_ (month from last event) (3 month avg)
  .                                   .
  .                                   .
  .                                   .
  .                                   .
  .                                   .
  .                                   .
50000      x (days in month [date]) (2 month avg)
```

Now, I am trying to replace these strings to something more meaningful, like

`data["Name"] = data["Name"].str.replace("avg_12_mon", "Average 12 Months")`

and this works as expected and string gets changed. However, when I try and replace the index 0 or 2 string value, it does not work.

`data["Name"] = data["Name"].str.replace("x (days in month [date]) (2 month avg)", "2 Month Average of Days Date")`

I even tried below to double check if I am not copying any spaces or things like that but it still doesn't work:

`data["Name"] = data["Name"].str.replace(data["Name"][0], "2 Month Average of Days Date")`

I have also tried re.sub but still cannot work through. May I know what I am doing wrong here? Thank you :)

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you add `regex=False`?

Comment: @BigBen Lol, you serious??? I was running like a headless chicken since morning trying all, and all I had to do is regex=False.. I wonder when I will reach your level of Python...but thank you so much, this worked as charm... :)

Comment: @user19077881 no, it does not have same result, pls try once from your side as well. I learnt this today after posting here.